# Creating a file name by adding two NSStrings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to load a file. The file name depends on a string stored in an array. In the following example, I would like to load tabRed.png. @"Red" is stored in an array.

This is what I tried:

```
UIImage *tabImage = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"tab%@.png", [self.currentNoteBook.tabColours objectAtIndex:0])];
```

But I only got "Red" as an output and not "tabRed.png". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImage *tabImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tab%@.png", [self.currentNoteBook.tabColours objectAtIndex:0]]];
```

You need to use `NSString stringWithFormat`. The comma operator (`,`) does quite a different thing.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator),

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token `,`) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

So when you write `(@"tab%@.png", [self.currentNoteBook.tabColours objectAtIndex:0])`, it actually discards the first string and returns the object in array which is just "Red".

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a new NSString for the file name.  The string @"tab%@.png" won't automatically replace the placeholder for you.  Use -stringWithFormat: as follows:

```
UIImage *tabImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tab%@.png", [self.currentNoteBook.tabColours objectAtIndex:0]]];
```